# Why my Nested loop output wont move to a new line

Tags: java, nested-loops

This should be the final output, but my code goes down a straight line.

```
   (^_^)
   (^_^)  (^_^)  
   (^_^)  (^_^)  (^_^)  
   (^_^)  (^_^)  (^_^)  (^_^)  
   (^_^)  (^_^)  (^_^)  (^_^)  (^_^)
```

The code:

```
   public class PP2A {

     public static final int MAX = 5; 

      public static void main(String[] args) {  
        loop();

    }

     public static void loop() {
       int count,number;

     for(count=1; count<=MAX;  count++) {
     for(number=1;  number<= count; number++) {
     System.out.println(" (^_^)  ");
     }
     System.out.println(); 
      }

      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change
`System.out.println(" (^_^)  ");`
to
`System.out.print(" (^_^)  ");`

Comment: Omggg you guys rock!! Such a silly mistake smh. Thanks a million!!!!!!!

Comment: No problem at all, I've made the same mistake. ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28%29):

> **`void java.io.PrintStream.println()`**: Terminates the current line by writing the line separator string. The line separator string is defined by the system property `line.separator`, and is not necessarily a single newline character (`'\n'`).

In other words,

```
System.out.println(s);
```

prints a *newline* after printing `s`.

**What can you do?** You could use:

```
System.out.print(s);
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks omg i really didn't notice what i did wrong lol

Answer (score 0):

change

```
System.out.println(" (^_^)  ");
```

to

```
System.out.print(" (^_^)  " + ((number == count) ? "\n" : ""));
```

And remove

```
System.out.println();
```

Complete solution:

```
    public static void loop() {
    int count, number;

    for (count = 1; count <= MAX; count++) {
        for (number = 1; number <= count; number++) {
            System.out.print(" (^_^)  " + ((number == count) ? "\n" : ""));
        }
    }

}
```